# Redirecting to DIV from ASP.NET button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have a one page website which one submit of the contact form sends an email. The contact form on my page is situated at the bottom above the footer. Ideally I would like my visitors to be redirected back to the `#bottom-contact` DIV after the page refreshes.

I redirect my visitors with this piece of code.

```
Response.Redirect("?messagesent=true#bottom-contact");
```

It sends the visitor to the URL below

```
http://okpidi.com/Default.aspx?messagesent=true#bottom-contact
```

As you can see it does not scroll to the bottom of the page where the `#bottom-contact` is located. I also send a parameter back to the page called `messagesent` as shown above.

I have been working with this for hours and can not seem to find out what I am doing wrong here.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest using an Ajax call to submit your form data

Comment: That won't work with a `div` but it would work if you change `bottom-contact` to a named anchor (`<a name='bottom-contact'>`)

Comment: FWIW, it looks like it loads as you intend (it goes immediately to the bottom contact form), but something else overrides it and scrolls the page back up to the top. I'd disable some of your other JS and see what's causing the conflict.